# Archive page not showing content that's defined in its file

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type called `How to videos`. Here is how I've registered it:

```html
register_post_type(
  'How to videos',
  theme_build_post_args(
    // $slug, $singular, $plural
    'how-to-videos', 'How to videos', 'How to videos',
    array(
      'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-video-alt3',
      'menu_position' => 20,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'public' => false,
      'supports' => array('title','thumbnail'),
    )
  )
);
```

I have created a file called `archive-how-to-videos.php` which currently looks like this:

```html
<body class="listingPage">
  <?php get_header(); ?>
    this is a test
  <?php get_footer(); ?>
</body>
```

I have flushed the permalinks multiple times via settings > permalinks in the WordPress dashboard. But, whenever I try to access `/how-to-videos`, the content doesn't display as defined in the file? For example, I have "this is a test" in my `archive-how-to-videos.php` file, but I cannot see it on the page (not even via inspecting the code on the page).

Currently, it only shows the header and footer, nothing defined in-between?

`theme_build_post_args` function below:

```html
function theme_build_post_args( $slug, $singular = 'Post', $plural = 'Posts', $args = array() ){
    $builder = new theme_PTTaxArgBuilder;
    return $builder->buildPostArgs($slug, $singular, $plural, $args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the post type has not been properly registered. Where did you get the theme_build_post_args function?

The post type name should only contain lowercase characters, so "How to videos" is invalid or it should be used as the post type label. The correct slug or post type name should be "how-to-videos".

> $post_type
>
> ```
> (string) (Required) Post type key. Must not exceed 20 characters and may only contain lowercase alphanumeric characters, dashes, and
> ```
>
> underscores. See sanitize_key().

You can find a register_post_type template in the documentation.

// https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/

Example:

```
function wpdocs_kantbtrue_init() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Recipes', 'Post type general name', 'recipe' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Recipe', 'Post type singular name', 'recipe' ),
        'menu_name'             => _x( 'Recipes', 'Admin Menu text', 'recipe' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => _x( 'Recipe', 'Add New on Toolbar', 'recipe' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'recipe' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New recipe', 'recipe' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New recipe', 'recipe' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit recipe', 'recipe' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View recipe', 'recipe' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All recipes', 'recipe' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search recipes', 'recipe' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent recipes:', 'recipe' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'No recipes found.', 'recipe' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'No recipes found in Trash.', 'recipe' ),
        'featured_image'        => _x( 'Recipe Cover Image', 'Overrides the “Featured Image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'recipe' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => _x( 'Set cover image', 'Overrides the “Set featured image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'recipe' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => _x( 'Remove cover image', 'Overrides the “Remove featured image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'recipe' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => _x( 'Use as cover image', 'Overrides the “Use as featured image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'recipe' ),
        'archives'              => _x( 'Recipe archives', 'The post type archive label used in nav menus. Default “Post Archives”. Added in 4.4', 'recipe' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => _x( 'Insert into recipe', 'Overrides the “Insert into post”/”Insert into page” phrase (used when inserting media into a post). Added in 4.4', 'recipe' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => _x( 'Uploaded to this recipe', 'Overrides the “Uploaded to this post”/”Uploaded to this page” phrase (used when viewing media attached to a post). Added in 4.4', 'recipe' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => _x( 'Filter recipes list', 'Screen reader text for the filter links heading on the post type listing screen. Default “Filter posts list”/”Filter pages list”. Added in 4.4', 'recipe' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => _x( 'Recipes list navigation', 'Screen reader text for the pagination heading on the post type listing screen. Default “Posts list navigation”/”Pages list navigation”. Added in 4.4', 'recipe' ),
        'items_list'            => _x( 'Recipes list', 'Screen reader text for the items list heading on the post type listing screen. Default “Posts list”/”Pages list”. Added in 4.4', 'recipe' ),
    );     
    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'description'        => 'Recipe custom post type.',
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'recipe' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => 20,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail' ),
        'taxonomies'         => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
        'show_in_rest'       => true
    );
      
    register_post_type( 'Recipe', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpdocs_kantbtrue_init' );
```

--- OR ---

You can also use a third party plugin like CPT UI.

// https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/